# Дублирование записей в SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос, таблицы, запись

```
create table Читатели_запрос
        (
        код_читателя    int Primary Key identity(1,1)   not null,
        фамилия char(20) not null,
        адрес   char(20)    not null,
        контактный_телефон  varchar(15) not null
        )
insert Читатели_запрос
(
        фамилия, адрес, контактный_телефон
        )
SELECT  фамилия, адрес, контактный_телефон
FROM    dbo.View_1

insert Читатели_запрос
(
        фамилия, адрес, контактный_телефон
        )
SELECT  фамилия, адрес, контактный_телефон
FROM    dbo.Читатели_2
where   дата_рождения <= '2001-01-01'
```

Есть таблица Читатели_запрос и при добавлении новых записей с помощью запросов, возникает проблема дублирования данных. Как сделать так, чтобы при выполнении запроса таблица игнорировала те же записи, что и были в предыдущем запросе?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В показанных записях НЕТ дублирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вначале получаем уникальные данные

```
1) SELECT DISTINCT <список полей по которым нужна уникальность>
2) Основной запрос со всеми необходимыми полями WHERE <запись IN (1)>
```

Comment: На мой взгляд, это плохой способ. Два запроса вместо одного. Низкая производительность при больших объёмах данных. @EUG217

Answer (score 1):

нужно добавить на столбец уникальный ключ.

```
create table Читатели_запрос
(
    код_читателя        int identity(1,1) not null,
    фамилия             char(20)          not null,
    адрес               char(20)          not null,
    контактный_телефон  varchar(15)       not null,
    constraint pk_код_читателя primary key (код_читателя),
    constraint uc_фамилия unique (фамилия)
)
```

Comment: Сообщение 2627, уровень 14, состояние 1, строка 1
Нарушено "uc_фамилия" ограничения UNIQUE KEY. Не удается вставить повторяющийся ключ в объект "dbo.Читатели_запрос". Повторяющееся значение ключа: (Мордвинов           ).
Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.

Время выполнения: 2019-10-27T21:57:36.4013162+03:00

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы он игнорировал повторяющиеся записи, а не выдавал ошибку о конфликте

Comment: напишите процедуру для этого

Comment: всё равно та же ошибка

Comment: @EUG217 - _мне нужно, чтобы он игнорировал повторяющиеся записи_ - это так не делается. Нельзя молча проглатывать ошибку. Вы **обязаны** обработать ошибку: залогировать ее, выдать сообщение пользователю (он же должен знать, что случайно ввел те же данные) и т. п.

Comment: Тут, вероятно, нужен композитный ключ, на несколько полей.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert Читатели_запрос
(
        фамилия, адрес, контактный_телефон
        )
SELECT  фамилия, адрес, контактный_телефон
FROM    dbo.View_1
UNION
SELECT  фамилия, адрес, контактный_телефон
FROM    dbo.Читатели_2
where   дата_рождения <= '2001-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Proсedure insertifnotexists(Код_читателя,... ) is
    Begin
    Select count(*) into cc from таблица where таблица.код_читателя = код_читателя 
     and... ;
     If cc > 0 then
     Insert into таблица(... ) values(... ) ;
     Commit;
      End if;
      End insertifnotexists;
```

Answer (score 0):

По факту мне помог @santavital. Оператор DISTINCT именно то, что я искал. Я решил эту задачу следующим образом:

1) Сначала ввёл запрос на создание таблицы Читатели_запрос и Читатели_запрос_PK(и там, и там пришлось убрать identity, т.к. с ним это сделать не возможно). При запросе Читатели_запрос я предварительно добавил некоторые записи.

```
create table Читатели_запрос
        (
        код_читателя    int not null,
        фамилия char(20) not null,
        адрес   char(20)    not null,
        контактный_телефон  varchar(15) not null
        )
insert Читатели_запрос
(
        код_читателя, фамилия, адрес, контактный_телефон
        )
SELECT distinct код_читателя, фамилия, адрес, контактный_телефон
FROM   dbo.View_1

create table Читатели_запрос_PK
        (
        код_читателя    int primary key not null,
        фамилия char(20) not null,
        адрес   char(20)    not null,
        контактный_телефон  varchar(15) not null
        )
```

2) После я написал запрос на добавление доп. данных в Читатели_запрос и под ним перенос данных из Читатели_запрос в Читатели запрос_PK с использование оператора DISTINCT.

````
insert Читатели_запрос
(
        код_читателя, фамилия, адрес, контактный_телефон
        )
SELECT  distinct код_читателя, фамилия, адрес, контактный_телефон
FROM    dbo.Читатели_2
where   дата_рождения <= '2001-01-01'

insert Читатели_запрос_PK
(
        код_читателя, фамилия, адрес, контактный_телефон
        )
SELECT  distinct код_читателя, фамилия,  адрес, контактный_телефон
FROM    Читатели_запрос```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YrMF.jpg
````